# laravel 5 how to add to $with / $appends fields in child model class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have several models which share some common functionality (due to their polymorphism) which I'd like to pull into a ResourceContentModel class (or even a trait).

The ResourceContentModel class would extend the eloquent Model class and my individual models would then extend ResourceContentModel.

My question is around the model fields like $with, $appends and $touches. If I make use of these for any of the common functionality in ResourceContentModel, then when I redefine them in my child model class, it overwrites the values I've set in my parent class.

Looking for some suggestions for a clean way around this?

For example:

```
class ResourceContentModel extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['resource']
    protected $appends = ['visibility']

    public function resource()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Resource::class, 'content');
    }

    public function getVisibilityAttribute()
    {
        return $this->resource->getPermissionScope(Permission::RESOURCE_VIEW);
    }
}

class Photo extends ResourceContentModel
{
    protected $with = ['someRelationship']
    protected $appends = ['some_other_property']

    THESE ARE A PROBLEM AS I LOSE THE VALUES IN ResourceContentModel
}
```

I'm after a clean way to do this so the child classes aren't overly changed by the fact I've slotted in an extra class in the hierarchy to gather the common code.

Comment: for `$appends` check https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/define-model-attributes-in-trait/replies/50522, for `$with` u can try https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#global-scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea if this will work...

```
class Photo extends ResourceContentModel
{
    public function __construct($attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->with = array_merge(['someRelationship'], parent::$this->with);
    }
}
```

Or perhaps add a method on ResourceContentModel to access the property.

```
class ResourceContentModel extends Model
{
    public function getParentWith()
    {
        return $this->with;
    }
}
```

then

```
class Photo extends ResourceContentModel
{
    public function __construct($attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->with = array_merge(['someRelationship'], parent::getParentWith());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

In the constructor of the 3rd snippet,

`$this->with = array_merge(['someRelationship'], parent->getParentWith());`

needed to be

`$this->with = array_merge(['someRelationship'], parent::getParentWith());`

Comment: Thanks, I like this, I used your first idea there, although I put the custom constructor in the ResourceContentModel class instead which meant the child classes could all just set $with and $appends like normal. Being protected and not private fields, the overridden values were accessible in the base class so I could merge them with the common values. Nice and tidy...

Comment: Good to hear, typing out `parent::$this->with` just seemed... odd. But I'm glad it worked, might have to use it someday myself =)

Comment: Yeah not sure about that particular syntax (I didnt know you could do that) but because I put your suggested logic in the parent class constructor I could just reference $this->with

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `parent::$this->appends` caused a PHP error in PHP 7.1.

This worked for me:

Parent model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;

class Model extends BaseModel
{
    public function __construct($attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->append([
            'everyChildModelAppendsThis',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Child model:

```
<?php

class ChildModel extends Model
{
    protected $appends = [
        'childModelStuff',
    ];
}
```